# Equivalence of “sticking” and “poking”

Tags: difference, vocabulary

> I can see the baby **sticking** out of mummy’s belly. I can't actually make out what parts they are.

> I can see the baby **poking** out of mummy’s belly. I can't actually make out what parts they are.

Do “sticking” and “poking” have the same meaning in this context?

Comment: I'd say in either case mummy needs to get to the hospital immediately, as the baby is not supposed to be rupturing her abdomen and waving its parts around in the air.

Comment: @Hellion lol. But what if this is asked by a junior or trainee doctor to her obstetrician?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, with a child saying your original sentences, it's just cute grammar to anyone around, and is not of any concern at all. (There would not be any concern for embarrassment, for example; people would think it cute/charming.) I thought I'd just share with you some ways you **can** describe this:

- "Yes that is the baby poking mama's belly!"
- "I think  you're right... the baby IS trying to stick her foot out of my stomach! But she's not going to be able to do that..." (You could say this to be funny if another adult was around and the baby was kicking hard.)
- See the baby poke? I think that's her foot!
- I think the baby is sticking his foot out. (not "out of my stomach")
- I think the baby is trying to stick his foot out of my stomach!
- The baby is moving in mama's belly.
- I can see the baby moving.
- I can see the baby moving in mama's belly.
- See the baby kicking?
- Yes I can see the baby kicking!
- You can feel the baby moving/kicking/poking.
- See the bulge in mama's belly?  I think that's her foot!
- "The bulge where the feet poke out seems rounded..." (from a webpage)
- "A wicked cool video of my baby kicking, moving, jumping and dancing in my 8 month..." (from a webpage)

Answer (score 3):

As Hellion has rather amusingly pointed out, "sticking out of something" or "poking out of something" generally means that whatever is doing the sticking or poking has gone entirely through the something out of which it is sticking or poking. Now, we could rephrase these a bit:

> I can see a part of the baby making mummy's belly stick out.
>   I can see a part of the baby poking at mummy's belly (and making it stick out).

Those would work, although perhaps they sound a bit awkward.

To answer your main question, however, the two sentences that you have used are essentially the same, as Hellion has also implied.  Poking out is a bit more specific, though.  Poking out implies something showing through a relatively small area of some sort, and also points more strongly to the force that caused the situation than sticking out does.

Consider this picture:

[image]

While someone might say these cars are poking out of the ground, I would say that it is more likely that they would say sticking out.  This is because they got poked (or stuck) *into* the ground to be in the position that they are in.  Poking out implies that they were in the ground and pushed their way out.  (Which is an amusing little fantasy, so of course you might hear this.)

Sticking out is also used in abstract senses, where poking isn't (at least, I can't think of any such, someone may feel free to correct me with an example).

> Among the many people that worked to get the job done, I think we can all agree that Joe's effort sticks out.
>
> The red you used on the door makes it stick out too much.  You might try a red that's a few shades less bright.

We wouldn't say poke out on either of these.  (We might well say "stand out", however, but that's a bit more formal.)

Comment: One other connotation that comes to mind is that *poking* generally implies motion or activity, whereas *sticking* can be used for a static situation like your car picture.

Comment: @Hellion Very true.